# Python: how to pass tuple elements from a tuple slice rather than tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I'm learning Python and haven't yet learned completely about how arg arrays are handled in function calls. That's what my question is about: I'm passing a slice from a tuple into a function expecting the function will see multiple arguments, but it's just seeing one. It's not clear to me if this is a normal pattern that I need to work with in the called function, or if I should be doing something differently.

In my project, I'm parsing a binary file format (OpenType font file). The format is a complex tree of many different struct types: some structs are comprised of basic binary types supported by `struct.unpack`, but some have members that are themselves complex structs. So, I'm creating a pattern for handling these in which `struct.unpack` is called with a format string for the entire complex struct, and then slices of the returned values are passed to the member struct types to interpret.

For example, for a given table type—let's call it `Foo`, the combined format string would be `'>HHH2H'`. The method in `Foo` that handles parsing for that type knows that this is divided into two members, a uint16 followed by a struct. (So, the format string was a combination of `">H"` and `">HH2H"`.) The call to `struct.unpack` returned a tuple of 5 elements. A slice of four of those elements will get passed to a method in the member type for it to interpret.

Here's this bit of code for one particular case:

```
    vals = struct.unpack(
        PaintFormat1._packedFormat,
        fileBytes[:PaintFormat1._packedSize]
        )

    color = ColorIndex.interpretUnpackedValues(vals[1:])
```

`PaintFormat1._packedFormat` is the format string for the entire complex structure, `'>HHH2H'`. `fileBytes` is a byte sequence that starts at the start of the `PaintFormat1` structure.

Now, I've defined the `ColorIndex.interpretUnpackedValues` method with a signature as follows:

```
    def interpretUnpackedValues(*vals):

        assert len(vals) == ColorIndex._numUnpackedValues
```

`ColorIndex._numUnpackedValues` is the expected number of arguments. The problem is that `vals[1:]` (from the calling context) is getting passed as a tuple, not as elements of the tuple. So, for instance, in one call the arguments received are `((17, 0, 0, 0),)`, not `(17, 0, 0, 0)`. Thus, `len(vals)` is 1, and the assert is tripped.

Another way to put this: I was expecting to write the assert using `len(vals)`, not `len(vals[0])`. And then to access the individual values as `vals[0]`, `vals[1]`, etc., not `vals[0][0]`, `vals[0][1]`...

How do I call so that multiple arguments are passed rather than a single tuple?

Or should I re-write the function definition to expect a single tuple and access member elements within that function?

(This will be a recurring pattern I use in many places, so I want to understand and keep the code as simple and readable as possible.)

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps take a list or list of lists instead of the unpack operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to unpack your arguments:

```
ColorIndex.interpretUnpackedValues(*vals[1:])
```